# New kubeconfig after k8s update?

Tags: kubernetes

When I update my kubernetes (e.g. from 1.7 to 1.8) do I need to download the new kubeconfig file? For some reason the previous one doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/), after re-installing or upgrading the k8s cluster, it is always good to use the updated / latest `kubeconfig` at `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` by doing the following so that stale / old `kubeconfig` is not used:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Steps to upgrade `kubeadm` from from 1.7 to 1.8 are [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm-upgrade-1-8/).

Comment: In my case the old kubeconfig is not working, the new one is working fine. My question is what is expected (standard policy). I mean, is this a *bug* or a *feature* ?

Comment: @PanosGeorgiadis Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks! After re-installing or upgrading kubernetes, the old `kubeconfig` will have old / wrong client certificates and may not work. Hence, it is always good to use the updated / latest `kubeconfig` (with the new client certificates) after re-installing or upgrading k8s.

Comment: I verified that kubeadm does that behind the since for you. During the `upgrade` it download the new `config`.